# C++ Smart Factory Design

Tags: c++, factory

Not c++11

I need to write a Factory in c++ that works like so:

1) The elements created are blocks of objects

2) The factory saves references to all such sub-objects.

3) The blocks are scale-able

Meaning:

```
class Block{
     MemberType member1;
     MemberType member2;
     MemberType member3;
     Block(){...}
}

class Factory{
     set<MemberType*> members1;
     set<MemberType*> members2;
     set<MemberType*> members3;

     Block& makeBlockInstance(){
           Block& currentBlock = *(new Block());

           members1.push_back(&(currentBlock.member1));
           members2.push_back(&(currentBlock.member2));
           members3.push_back(&(currentBlock.member3)); 

           return currentBlock;
     }
}
```

- please don't mind syntax errors or minor details, the code is to make a point.

What I need is a way to add or remove members from `Block`, in such a way that would AUTOMATICALLY create or delete the `set<MemberType*> members#`, and the `members#.push_back(...)`.

Is this possible?
It seems like something that is done via reflection, but I want some non-reflection way of doing this, statically.

Thanks.

Comment: You should rather use a `std::unique_ptr<MemberType>` or `std::shared_ptr<MemberType>` to be stored in the set, instead of managing the memory de-/allocation yourself.

Comment: Can `Block` be (variadic) templated ?

Comment: For now, just for the sake of the theoretic debate about the factory, everything is simple. regular pointers, regular types, no templates.

Comment: I mean, is a solution which chage current `Block`/`Factory` declaration to be template acceptable (So `Block<Ts...>` may knows its type).

Comment: Acceptable. I hope it will do

Answer (score 2):

Following may help:

```
template<typename ... Ts> struct BlockFactoryT;

template<typename ... Ts>
struct BlockT
{
    using Factory = BlockFactoryT<Ts...>;

    BlockT(){...}

    std::tuple<Ts...> members;
};

template<Ts...>
struct BlockFactoryT{
    using Block = BlockT<Ts...>;
    std::tuple<set<Ts*>> members_sets;

    std::unique_ptr<Block> makeBlockInstance()
    {
        return makeBlockInstanceImpl(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>());
    }

    template<std::size_t ... Is>
    std::unique_ptr<Block> makeBlockInstanceImpl(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        auto block = std::make_unique<Block>();

        const int dummy[] = {0,
            (std::get<Is>(members_sets).insert(&std::get<Is>(block->members)), 0)...};
        static_cast<void>(dummy); // Remove warning for unused variable
        return block;
    }
};
```

And for simplicity:

```
using MyBlock = BlockT<MemberType, MemberType, MemberType2>;
using MyFactory = typename MyBlockT::Factory;
```

Comment: Im so sorry -i should have stated - not c++11. Is there something that compiles on earlier versions?

Comment: @Gulzar: Instead of variadic template, you may use hard coded number (10?) with `void` as default parameter. I think that (old) boost has (limited) implementation for `tuple` and `get` for C++03

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if someone could write some code example that solves this, not in c++11,
This would be greatly appreciated.
I don't understand What you meant by using a hard coded number and a default void. Please add some code
Thanks!

Comment: @Gulzar: you may use `boost::tuple`, and for the C++03 version of variadic, something like `template<
    typename T1 = unspecified,
    typename T2 = unspecified,
    ...
    typename TN = unspecified>
class tuple;` (with hardcoded `N`)

Comment: no better more general solution?
10 isn't enough for me, and so is 100

Comment: @Gulzar: if type are identical, you may consider array. if 10/100 is not enough, you may use `type_list` for unlimited size, but it would probably conplicated the code...